# Epsilon-N proof

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Hello I want to prove that

$$\frac{1+\sin n}{n^2+1}\rightarrow0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow\infty$$

Using the Epsilon-N proof. I'm not sure what to do during the scratchwork. How do I work with the $\sin n$ ?

Comment: Consider carefully what you mean by an $\epsilon-N$ proof. Can you demonstrate that, for all values $n>N$, your expression _must_ be less than some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$? As for dealing with $\sin n$, consider the range of $\sin$. Will $\sin n$ ever be greater than $1$?

Comment: Note that $|\sin n|\le 1$

Comment: $\sin$ is bounded, so replace it by $\pm 1$.

Comment: Ahh yeap. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can consider choosing $n$ to be large enough that $$\left|\frac{1+\sin n}{n^2+1}\right|\le \frac{2}{n^2}< \epsilon$$

Try to solve for how big $n$ should be for $\frac2{n^2} < \epsilon$ to hold and hence we can bound our original function.